# Finding pdf of X+Y - Finan 42.2

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, actuarial-science

I am looking through Marcel Finan's 'A Probability Course for the Actuaries' and I am stuck on problem 42.2. It is as follows:

> Let X be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$ and Y be a uniform random variable on [0,1]. Find the probability density function of X+Y.

I have $f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, x \ge 1$ and $f_Y(y) = 1, 0 \le y \le 1$.

I am kind of lost as to where to go from there. According to the solution key, the final answer should come out relatively 'nice', but it's in two different pieces - one with $0 \le a \le 1$ and the other with $a \ge 1$.  I can see from the integration region why there would be two separate pieces. The real issue isn't with that. I think I'm just setting up my integrals incorrectly.

For $0 \le a \le 1$ I have

> $f_{X+Y}(a) = \int_0^1 \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$

Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: uhh addition of independent random variables corresponds to convolution of densities, so say for $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$ you should have a double integral rather than you wrote there. Here's a hint: $X+Y \leq \alpha$ is equivalent to $ X \leq Y - \alpha$ and $ 0 \leq Y \leq \alpha$.

Comment: And that's a sticky point. On page 330, he gives the result that the convolution essentially CAN be written as a single integral. I have tried writing out the CDF as a double integral and then differentiating with respect to a as suggested in text, but that proved to be relatively fruitless as well. I will try the limits you suggested and see if that gets me somewhere better.

Comment: @air - That's exactly the hint I needed. I was integrating y from 0 to 1 instead of 0 to a. All is fine now. Thanks! (If you write your hint up as an 'answer', I'll star it or whatever so you get the reputation for it.

Comment: Glad to hear this solved it! Also posted my comment as an answer (while also fixing the obvious typo in my comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition of independent random variables corresponds to convolution of distributions so say for $0\leq \alpha \leq 1$ you should have a double integral rather than a single integral (in terms of densities).

Here's a hint to get your started for $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$:

$X+Y \leq \alpha$ is equivalent to $0 \leq X \leq \alpha-Y$ and $0\leq Y \leq \alpha$.